# Amazon Cognito: is it correct design if I will store user settings as a custom attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html) I found that

> Not all information about your users should be stored in attributes. For example, user data that changes frequently, such as usage statistics or game scores, should be kept in a separate data store, such as Amazon Cognito Sync or Amazon DynamoDB.

But I do not found information - why Amazon does not recommend to store for example statistic in Cognito - right with other user data. I think that this is convenient to store all data about user in one place - when this is only a strings of data and not many rows.

For example user preferences - is it a data that changes frequently? Some of them not, so - where to store them - in DynamoDB or inside Cognito? What the pros and cons? Speed? Price? Convenient api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, Cognito User Pools is meant for data that changes infrequently such as user settings for an app. I would also assume that depending on the use case, user preferences change infrequently. It's not meant for data that changes very frequently such as user's current geographic location so for example if you had an app that tracks the user's location, you would have to store that data in another store such as DynamoDb.